# Regex JavaScript to search code in a sentence

Tags: regex

I have the sentence:
"Hello Mario your registration in 12/01/2016 and your code is: 1234."

I want a regex to take only the code "1234".

The problem is the year in the sentence because I can't use a simple regex to take 4 number.

Thanks

Comment: how about a colon, a single space, followed by 4 numbers?

Comment: What are the unique conditions of the code? Is it always 4 digits? Always at the end? Always preceded by a colon and a space?

Comment: The code is always after the words "code is:" and is 4 digits.

Comment: How about `code\s+is:\s*(\d+)` ?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best option should be:

```
/([0-9]+)(?:\.$)/
```

And take the first match group.

Comment: if you want to check the number of digits you can use `/(?:[^0-9])([0-9]{4})(?:\.$)/` instead. It will bring a four digit number